# Batch Script For delete file

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I'm using FTP batch file to transfer file to every 10 min & then file move to another location.But sometime move file process getting stuck & FTP process not working properly. I need to write batch file if file count > 100 then Ftp.BAT & MOVE FILE.BAT need to delete. please help

```html
  @echo OFF

:ftp configuration

echo USERNAME> ftp.tmp
echo PASSWORD>> ftp.tmp
echo bi>> ftp.tmp

FOR  %%X IN (*.csv) DO (
ECHO put %%X >> ftp.tmp 
ECHO move %%X G:\LOCAL\ >> moveFile.bat
)

echo bye>> ftp.tmp

:start FTP process

ftp -s:E:\GBR\RECON\MAC\ftp.tmp  12.25.65.48

call moveFile.bat
DEL ftp.tmp
DEL moveFile.bat
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: What do you mean by the `move` getting stuck? `Move` doesn't just "get stuck."

Comment: Getting stuck mean sometimes through Symantec virus guard FTP process block. i do not have access to disable. I have to manually remove ftp.tmp file & move.tmp file.

Comment: Can you show us an exact copy of the batch output, when the error occurs? Can you show us the code of `moveFile.bat`?